# Game input display is slow

Tags: monogame, input

I'm trying to build a very small example to run input logic but i'm facing a small issue. The code below is runnable with MonoGame v3.7.0.1708.

My problem is that whenever you press a key (here the example is for the D key) i'm displaying a small text on the console.

But you will see if you run the code that the display happens with lag. When i press the "D" key on my keyboard, the message is displayed only ~200ms after the input.

You can for example do a fast press on the keyboard and the message will be displayed after the release of the key.

Does anyone have any idea why it's happening? Thanks!

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;

namespace TestProject
{
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    GameInput gameInput;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        gameInput = new GameInput();
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent() {}

    protected override void UnloadContent() {}

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();
        base.Update(gameTime);
        gameInput.Update();
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    }
}

public class GameInput
{
    public bool _dKeyPressed = false;

    public void Update()
    {
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            if (!_dKeyPressed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[GameInput] D key is pressed.");
            }
            _dKeyPressed = true;
        }
        else if (_dKeyPressed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[GameInput] D key is released.");
            _dKeyPressed = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Outputting to the console is likely the slowest part of this. Have you tried signalling the key press with something you can update more rapidly, like changing the clear colour you wipe in your Draw step?

Comment: Indeed, setting a color for the background when pressing a key is updating the background with the same speed as my finder. Why does the console is that slow ?

Comment: Is your console output simply getting buffered?  What happens if you flush the buffer at the end of your update?  Note that you will NOT want to do this in your application (it'll slow everything down) but testing it might help you see what's happening.

Comment: What is the method to flush the buffer ? Console.out.flush() ?

Comment: That looks about right, but my C# is a little rusty.  In fact, Write*Line* (vs Write) might flush implicitly, now that I think about it.  Should be quick enough to test, though.

Comment: I ran your code on my machine. I'll just say that it seemed very performant to me. I couldn't discern any lag or delay, and humans can usually detect 200ms+ of delay. Writing stuff to the console window is not exactly the fastest operation, but I'm not seeing the delay you're talking about, unfortunately.